# Starting/Pausing canvas animation with a button click

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, setinterval

I am trying to get a simple snake game running where the game is off default and you click Start to begin.

the StartStop button's code:

```
StartStop.onclick = function()
{
    //flip the name on the button
    if (StartStop.value = "Start")
    {
        StartStop.value = "Stop";
        update();
    }
    else
    {
        StartStop.value = "Start";
        clearInterval(update);
    }
}
```

code inside update() starts the animation:

```
function update()
{
    setInterval(function()
    {
        console.log(snake.x + ", " + snake.y);
        //check for collisions
        //if no collisions move and draw snake
        snake.x += velocity[vi][0];
        snake.y += velocity[vi][1];
        snake.draw();
    },30);
}
```

My thought process was when the button's text value is Start, it changes the text to Stop and calls update() which calls setInterval().
Then when you click the button and the text value is Stop, it calls clearInterval(timer) to stop the animation

I think I am not using setInterval correctly, any ideas on how to get it to start and stop on a button click?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing my code to this:

```
StartStop.onclick = function()
{
    if (StartStop.value == "Start")
    {
        StartStop.value = "Stop";
        var timer = setInterval(
        function()
        {
        if (StartStop.value == "Stop")
        {
            console.log(snake.x + ", " + snake.y);
            //check for collisions
            //if no collisions move and draw snake
            snake.x += velocity[vi][0];
            snake.y += velocity[vi][1];
            snake.draw();
        }
        else
        {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        },30);
    }
    else
        StartStop.value = "Start";
}
```